# codeigniter get last insert id from model to use as redirect parameter

Tags: codeigniter

I need to get the insert ID to be used in my controller, the problem is my model function has several data arrays, and I need the insert ID of the 1st array. therefor if I try to get the insert ID on my controller obviously its grabbing the 2nd insert ID and not the 1st.

I'm not sure this makes sense but here is an example:

## Model

```
public function add() { 

    $data = array(
        'name' => $_POST['companyName']
        ,'type' => $_POST['companyType']
        ,'active' => '1');

    $this->db->insert('company', $data);

    $cid = $this->db->insert_id();

    $data2 = array(
        'cid' => $cid
        ,'name' => $_POST['locationName']
        ,'address' => $_POST['locationAddress']);

    $this->db->insert('locations', $data2);
}
```

This is working fine...However after this runs, on my controller the redirect is getting the data2 last insert which makes my redirect wrong.

## Controller

```
public function add() {

    if (isset($_POST["add"]))
    {
        $this->Company_model->add();
        $id = $this->db->insert_id();
        redirect('company/view/'.$cid);
    }

    $data['states']  = $this->Company_model->

}
```

Any help would be greatful!

Comment: Assign the value from the `$this->db->insert_id();` to a variable inside the model and return it once the model functions are complete. From the controller, you just grab the return value of the model call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were very close. Instead of repeating `$id = $this->db->insert_id();` in your controller, you can return the $cid from your models method.

## Model

```
public function add()   { 
    $data = array(
        'name' => $_POST['companyName']
        ,'type' => $_POST['companyType']
        ,'active' => '1');
    $this->db->insert('company', $data);

    $cid = $this->db->insert_id();
    $data2 = array(
                   'cid' => $cid
                   ,'name' => $_POST['locationName']
                   ,'address' => $_POST['locationAddress']);
    $this->db->insert('locations', $data2);

    // This returns your first inserts id
    return $cid;
}
```

## Controller

```
public function add() {

    if (isset($_POST["add"]))
    {
        $id = $this->Company_model->add();
        redirect('company/view/'.$id);
    }
    ...
```

Comment: I tried that but it redirects me to : company/view/0   which 0 is not correct. Thanks for your help by the way.

Comment: Are you using `company/view/$id` or `company/view/$cid` ? . I noticed on your code you were using $cid, but defining it as $id. Make sure you variable names match. Also, have you confirmed your insert statements are working by checking the db?

Comment: yep you were correct, i usually use cid as my company id, and forgot to change it to ID since thats what we were calling. its working now thanks!